# Ruby: Form not submit - ActionController::Parameters permitted: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, actioncontroller

After adding some gems in my project my form doesn´t create entries anymore.

I added `devise` and `active admin` and after that my form submit stopped working.
When i try to debug i got that message:

```
# posts_controller.rb

def create
  render plain: params[:post].inspect
end
```

Output:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"firstname"=>"Andreas", "lastname"=>"", "street"=>"", "city_code"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "country"=>""} permitted: false>
```

This is the production code:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if(@post.save)
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

It submits the form but no database entry will generated.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Check your `@post.errors` before your `render 'new'` line to see if you have validation errors.

Comment: I simply put `@post.errors` the line about `render`?
This gives me a `undefined method "errors" for nil:NilClass`. 
Or how can i do that?

Does the Server log help with that?

`Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-02-15 16:34:16 +0100
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"dD230A0PIRSM3Z0nnMU14vZbB610CDOFc80OzHNhZe7HcfEha0LzHUZCCx3xUCxujlKK5AXapr/ahpnMZ/RB5A==", "post"=>{"firstname"=>"Test" }, "commit"=>"Save Post"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
`

Comment: Add a line inside your `else` block, before your `render` statement: `puts @post.errors.messages` and then look at your server console when you try to create a new post. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors

Comment: Can you put the post_params method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help! 
I accidentally had a required for an extra field in my controller which doesn’t exists.